# Connect a bridge interface from other machine

Tags: linux, network-interface, bridge

this is my first post, sorry for any inconvenience.

I want to link a bridged interface from another machine to my laptop. So that any packets sent from my laptop can be sent both interfaces from the the other machine. Is it possible?

example configuration:

```
laptop -----eth----- |       machine     |
                     |br [iface0, iface1]|
```

any packet sent from laptop should be sent from iface0 and iface1.
And any packet received from iface0 or iface1 should be available by laptop ethernet.

I don't know if it is possible?

Comment: Could you say something about what you are trying to achieve by this? Is it port mirroring, failover, load balancing or something else?

Comment: I could be so wrong, but I want to try if I could increase bandwidth using this approach

Comment: The laptop's bandwidth would probably not be increased as it is still limited by its single network interface and the single line to the other machine.